# Illustrator cs6 - how can i erase lines like that?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, path

Here's a part of my artwork, and  I want to erase just the lines between the squares.

Here's a picture of what I want to do:

[image]

all the black lines marked with red lines have to be erased.

**My question is if I can erase them by drawing a line above the black lines with some tool, like cutting the black lines between the squares and not the lines that are inside the squares?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same result even easier :) You need to use "Divide" tool of the "Pathfinder" panel. If you don't have this panel opened just go to "Main menu --> Window --> Pathfinder" to make it visible.

Here's a short screencast to show this tool in action: 
http://quick.as/6aV5sP65B

Hope you'll find it helpful :)
Have a nice day!

Comment: As @Metis suggested below, you can alternatively use a Shape Builder tool. Here's another short screencast: http://quick.as/d4oYul0Gj. The difference between these 2 methods is that you get a difference structure though the result will be looking the same. After using the Divide tool you'll make each window of the building containing 4 squares. If you'll use the Shaper Builder tool each window will contain an initial square and 2 lines as separators. Feel free to decide what's better for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Select all the windows and paths....

Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**

Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key

Drag across what you *don't* want.

This will have a tendency to make each of the 4 window panes separate shapes rather than one shape with two lines over it.

**NOTE:** You will want to ensure your dividing lines actually touch the edges of the window shapes. You've got a couple lines that don't fully extend to window edges.